# Program crash on array index assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, indexing, stack

I'm having a little problem here.
Every time I run the code below, my program just crash.

```
void Wingcod::push(byte b)
{
    stack[stackp] = b;
    stackp++;
    if(stackp >= stacks)
    {
        stacks += 16;
        try
        {
            realloc(stack,stacks);
        }catch(bad_alloc*)
        {
            cerr << "STACK OVERFLOW";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And stack, stackp and stacks is defined like this:

```
stacks = 8;
stackp = 0;
stack = new byte[stacks];
```

And byte is just a `unsigned char`.

Comment: what type are you declaring stackp?

Comment: did you try to debug with breakpoints and see what happens?

Comment: Why not use C++ instead? You can have a handy `std::vector<byte>` that does exactly what you need.

Comment: When i step into the push function, all the variable fields in the debugger turn blank. Weird.

Comment: @Kerrek SB this might sound a bit weird, but i need something more low level than a vector.

Comment: Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression ((this)->size)
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Comment: @TheBreadCat: no, I assure you, you don't.  Also, are [these](http://stackoverflow.com/users/728738) [users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/734568) also yourself?

Comment: @MooingDuck due to account management problems, yes those are mine :/   and i assure, i need something lower level than a vector.

Answer (score 6):

You're not allowed to use `realloc()` on a pointer that was allocated with `new`.

Maybe try something like the following instead of `realloc()`:

```
        byte* tmp = new byte[stacks];
        delete [] stack;
        stack = tmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

`realloc` doesn't throw exceptions as it's not related to `new`, but C's `malloc`. It also doesn't set the pointer.

```
stacks = 8;
stackp = 0;
stack = static_cast<byte*>(malloc(stacks * sizeof(byte)));

void Wingcod::push(byte b)
{
    stack[stackp] = b;
    stackp++;
    if(stackp >= stacks)
    {
        stacks += 16;
        if(!(stack = static_cast<byte*>(realloc(stack,stacks * sizeof(byte))))) {
            cerr << "STACK OVERFLOW";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't change the pointer" seems to be an important part of the crash.

Comment: Yeah, it's a solution, but not to my current problem. you see the crash happens at the first line in the function, the first time i run it.

Comment: @TheBreadCat You can post another question with more code if you think the problem is  something else. I was thinking that the calling object (this pointer) might be invalid.

Comment: the wc->push() code is the same as this.push(), it's just a static reference.

Comment: @TheBreadCat Why is `wc` a pointer? Are you 100% sure it's not NULL?

Comment: as i said wc is this in the code im running, so it's not null.  wc is the only instance of WingCod.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a pointer allocated with `new T[n]` as an argument for `realloc()`. The pointers working with `realloc()` have to come from the `malloc()` family of functions (`malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`). Personally, I wouldn't use any of this but rather use `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/), Realloc only works on a pointer to memory previously assigned by alloc. Try using malloc